# Query to show per week, per day, per hour

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm working in PLSQL, trying to find event counts for a given week, broken down by day and hour.

Essentially I want to plug in the week and then have the count of events such that I can easily discern counts >1M per day AND 300k per hour (=GOLD), 500k per day and 200k per hour (silver), 100k per day 30k per hour.

I'm trying something like this to get data per day, but I'm not sure how to break it down per day, per hour.  Oracle rookie here.

```
    SELECT TO_CHAR(TRUNC(store.transaction_datetime, 'HH'), 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS'), Identifier,
         COUNT (*)
    FROM data.stats store
  WHERE store.transaction_datetime >= '2016-09-04 00:00:00' 
  AND store.transaction_datetime <= '2016-09-10 23:59:59'
GROUP BY Identifier, TO_CHAR (TRUNC (store.transaction_datetime, 'HH'), 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
ORDER BY TO_CHAR (TRUNC (store.transaction_datetime, 'HH'), 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') ASC;
```

anything I can throw into excel and perform counts will work for me

any help appreciated

Comment: Hour query breaks down the data by hour, not day.  Please add sample data and desired results.

Comment: please add DDL/inserts of test data, expected results.

Answer (score 0):

Let me know if it helps:

```
SELECT T.*,
       CASE WHEN CNT_PER_DAY > ... AND CNT_PER_HOUR > ... THEN 'GOLD'
            WHEN CNT_PER_DAY > ... AND CNT_PER_HOUR > ...  THEN 'SILVER'
            WHEN CNT_PER_DAY > ... AND CNT_PER_HOUR > ... 'BRONZE'
            ELSE ...
       END CATEGORY  
FROM (
     SELECT DISTINCT 
            Identifier,
            TO_CHAR(TRUNC(store.transaction_datetime, 'HH'), 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') HOUR_TIME,
            COUNT (*) OVER (PARTITION BY Identifier,TRUNC(store.transaction_datetime, 'HH')) CNT_PER_HOUR,
            TO_CHAR(TRUNC(store.transaction_datetime, 'DD'), 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') DAY_TIME,
            COUNT (*) OVER (PARTITION BY Identifier,TRUNC(store.transaction_datetime, 'DD')) CNT_PER_DAY,
            store.transaction_datetime
     FROM   data.stats store
     WHERE  store.transaction_datetime >= '2016-09-04 00:00:00' 
     AND    store.transaction_datetime <= '2016-09-10 23:59:59') T
ORDER BY TO_CHAR (TRUNC (T.transaction_datetime, 'HH'), 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') ASC;
```